# Non-linear differential-integral equation which becomes second degree polynomial.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, soft-question, integral-equations

How can I solve a differential equation like this one?

$$k \to y(k), \forall k\in[a,b]\subset \mathbb R$$

$$y(k)^2=\int_{k}^{k+\Delta} y'(t)dt$$
where $\Delta$ independent of $k$ has primitive function:
$$y(k)^2 = y(k+\Delta)-y(k)$$

This becomes some kind of second degree polynomial equation for each point along the definition space. How to approach it? And maybe more importantly, what are these kinds of equations called if I want to read about them?

Comment: The first equation is confusing. You have $\Delta_t$ appearing in the upper bound of the integral. Is this a constant, or does it depend on $t$? I ask because $t$ is also the dummy variable of integration.

Comment: @parsiad : Yes you are right, it is not dependent on t. I will change it's name.

Comment: You can read this as a recursion equation for $a_j=y(k_0+jΔ)$, $a_{j+1}=a_j+a_j^2$. It can be explored by considering $b_j=1/a_j$ where $b_{j+1}=b_j-1+O(b_j^{-1})$, so approximately $b_{n+j}\approx b_n-j$ if $|b_n|\gg1$.

Comment: @LutzL that is a very good observation. Please make an answer of it if you feel like it.

Comment: What might also be useful is to specify the boundary condition. E.g., Do you have a boundary condition at $k=0$ and want to find a solution $y \colon [0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$? Or do you want a solution on the whole space?

Comment: @parsiad : I want a function for some compact subset of the real line. Maybe I should write that out...